# Make tab key go to Next Input Box in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I want to make the tab key work and a next field option. When it is hit it should act like it does on a register or login form and go from one input box to the next. I can't figure out how though, does anybody know?

I have tried the TabKeyBehavior Property in the properties menu for each input box, but this just makes it so the input box allows the user to add a tab space, not progress in the inputs.

Comment: Setting the `Index` should help.

Comment: Where can I find the index?

Comment: In a *UserForm*? http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/HV080805681.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is View --> TabOrder in VBE manu what you are lookng for?